# Check if user input is in between time

Tags: php, mysql

I have this system function where a user sends an invitation to a official. To illustrate, the official has in his calendar a 3-day retreat. In the database, it looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
|  name   | date_start |  date_end  |  time  | time_end |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
| Retreat | 2018-01-16 | 2018-01-18 | 9:00AM | 12:00PM  |
| Retreat | 2018-01-17 | 2018-01-18 | 9:00AM | 12:00PM  |
| Retreat | 2018-01-18 | 2018-01-18 | 9:00AM | 12:00PM  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------+----------+
```

The user wants to send a two-day event invitation to the official on `2018-01-17 to 2018-01-19` at `10:00AM to 11:00AM` for those days. How do I reject his input if his proposed date and time are anywhere in between the current date and time in the database?

So far, this is what I've worked with

```
$q_date = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date_start` = '$date' AND `time` = '$time_f' AND `pastor_id` = '$id'");
$count_date = mysqli_num_rows($q_date);
if ($count_date > 0) {
    echo "<p>Sorry, this time is occupied. Please select another schedule</p>";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack and is not suitable for production. Consider using [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or if your code base isn't that large, switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as it's compatible with more webservers than MySQLi :)

Comment: Side note: Why don't you use a DATETIME type and omit the last 2 columns, it would make things much simpler.

Comment: *"How do I reject his input if his proposed date and time are anywhere in between the current date and time in the database?"* - Use either BETWEEN or `> ... <` operators.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner because I need to display each event on each day. E.g. if the two columns were `2018-01-16` and `2018-01-18`, I wouldn't be able to display all the event details on `2018-01-17`. I'm putting this in a calendar grid and highlighting all the dates that has an event on it, so if that's the case `2018-01-17` wouldn't be included in the highlight though it's in between

Comment: I understand. Well, if you're going to want to go that route, you shouldn't be storing times as strings, but as a `TIME` format. String dates require more resources than what is needed.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's stored as `TIME` format on my database, for the question I just simplified it as I think it would be more understandable `9:40PM` looks like `09:00:00` on my database. But nonetheless, thank you. I highly I appreciate the help :)

Comment: for the sake of *perfect* clarity, I feel you should edit your post so that it contains actuals. This could have a bearing on possible answers. Did you try that answer given below? If it solved it, consider accepting it. If it hasn't, then you should tell them about it.

Comment: You can still use a datetime for this if you want to display each event on each day, you will just ignore the time for parts of it. This would be even more specific, than what you do now, since the events don't actually overlap, even though they look like it on your schedule since the first line runs 51 hours. The datetimes would look like this.

Start `2018-01-16 09:00:00`  -  
End `2018-01-16 12:00:00`  -  
Start `2018-01-17 09:00:00`  -  
End `2018-01-17 12:00:00`  -  
Start `2018-01-18 09:00:00`  -  
End `2018-01-18 12:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a BETWEEN condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` 
WHERE 
('$date' BETWEEN `date_start` AND `date_end`)
AND
('$time_f' BETWEEN `time` AND `time_end`)
AND `pastor_id` = '$id'
```

Assuming the query worked before, this will find you what you were looking for.

Comment: OP take note of this answer! It has the benefit of quicker execution time